# Почему push не срабатывает?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть вот такой JSON:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "200":[]
    }]
}
```

Почему при преобразовании в объект push срабатывает только на `data.push(array)` и отдает:

`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"`

при попытке добавления данных через `data["200"].push(array)`

Как в таком случае добавлять элементы в JSON где ключом массива является число?

Comment: Проблема не в том, что 200 - число, а в том, что по ключу data у вас массив. И  если вы хотите получить объект, то вам нужно обращаться по его индексу в массиве, ака **data[0]['200'].push(array)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором

```js
var obj = {
  data: [
  {
    200: []
  }
  ]
};

var array1 = "Aloha";

obj.data[0]["200"].push(array1);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: А чем же 0 отличается от 200, что первый без кавычек, а второй с кавычками?)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, по сути ничем. Мы могли бы написать в обоих случаях число или в обоих случаях строку. Но с моей точки зрения, код становится очевиднее, если к массивам, мы обращаемся с значением числового типа, а к обычным объектам с значением строкового.